# SSIS Designer is running VERY slowly

Tags: ssis

I am developing an SQL Server Integration Services package.  I have been doing some major refactoring to this package, and now the designer is running really slowly.  Even moving components around the screen causes the designer to hang for 2-3 minutes.  Looking at the task manager Visual Studio is consuming around 80% of the CPU during this period.

Does anyone have any ideas about this slow performance?

Comment: If you go into Event Viewer and look in the System and Application event logs, do you see any warnings?

Comment: Good idea - I will check that!

Answer (score 1):

How big is your package? Are you attempting to perform a whole ETL in a single package?

It helps to keep your packages small, and manage the orchestration in a master package.

This helps with SCC as well.

Edit:
To call one package from another, the standard way is to use an "Execute Package Task" from the toolbox.  However, with very large sets of packages this too can become cumbersome and it can become easier to use NAnt/MSbuild to manage the orchestration.

Comment: Chris - thanks for your response.  Yes - the package in question is relatively large.  Have you any suggestions about how to manage the master-child package relationship - given that it is not possible to call one package from another?

Answer (score 0):

BIDS has always been a little shall we say 'bloated'
You need at least 2GB of RAM on your machine so that you can do stuff. Once it starts up I usually have no problem and sometimes have 2 instances open

I would say start shutting down any programs and services you don't need while using BIDS

Answer (score 0):

Are you using BIDS helper?

I have found that it can sometimes get corrupted and slow down the whole of visual studio.

Uninstalling and reinstalling BIDS helper has fixed this for me.

Answer (score 0):

http://sqlblog.com/blogs/jorg_klein/archive/2010/01/04/ssis-package-design-pattern-for-loading-a-data-warehouse.aspx

"This parent/child package design pattern for loading a Data Warehouse gives you all the flexibility and functionality you need."

Answer (score 0):

Look at the errors that have raised in the developer. Maybe you have an element that is raising the error count and the cross validation between elemets is draining your resources.

This question I just open for the issue in hands, maybe it can be of help:

[SSIS is running extremely slow in designer view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42423158/ssis-is-running-extremely-slow-in-designer-view/42423159#42423159)