# SSIS is running extremely slow in designer view

Tags: sql-server, ssis, ssis-2008

First, thank you for your time and consideration. Let me start by providing some context to my problem.

I'm working on an ETL package which contains some data flows.

[image]

One of those have 47 elements as described in the picture:

[image]

I need to change the metadata in the Source, but when the error/warning push the validation BIDS melt down and gets super slow, imposible to work on any element. 
I have tried with Delay Validation, Metadata validation and even try with the solutions in the next articles/posts:

[SSIS Designer is running VERY slowly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/769193/ssis-designer-is-running-very-slowly)

[Why my BIDS is slow in design mode ?](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/farukcelik/2009/02/03/why-my-bids-is-slow-in-design-mode/)

[SSIS package reacts slow in BIDS](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic472867-148-1.aspx)

I can't find a solution to this that doesn't imply making again the dataflow from scratch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a couple of hours, asking a lot of collegues, reading a lot of posts online I realized that an enourmous amount of validation errors were comming from the Union All marked in the picture.

[image]

Delete it errased most of the validation errors that were consuming BIDS resources.

So I deleted the element in question and then I changed the metadata, BIDS's performance stayed optimal through the edition process. Then I added the Union All again and conected the flows.